# UI/UX for menu tab, 1 main function has only 1 sub-function and that sub-function also has just 1 sub-function

Tags: website-design, menu, information-architecture

I have a context of a function menu for an auto-recruiting system(ATS) briefing below.

I have three function cards,

1. **Position**
2. **Question Pack**
3. **Question**.

The concept is that a **Position** includes some **question** **packs**, and a question pack includes some **questions**.

Use Case: On creating a Position, a question pack should be added to it and continue to add questions to this question pack.

How should the menu tab be arranged for this use case?

For Ref: My idea is to **delete** these two functions:

**Question Packs and Question**, and bring them to the page of **Position**. *However, the Users still want to have an overview of all the
Question Pack and Question they have created.*

[image]
[image]

Comment: As is it looks redundant, but that may be because the big picture os still fuzzy.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to delete those two menus Question Packs and Question, then make it into 2 section steps in the Position menu

Comment: Cool ! Close the question in case you do not need further more answers please. Would be of great help to maintain the sanity of open questions content .